# Correct way of calling a c function that expects const char8 string[] as parameter

Tags: c, pointers

Inside an ISR of a microcontroller I am attempting to call a function as follows:

```
//adc.c
static volatile char uartBuf[6]={0};

CY_ISR(ISR_ADC)
{

for (uint8_t i=0; i < NS; i++)
  total += adc2_buffer0[i];

uartBuf[0] = total >> 24 & 0xFF;
uartBuf[1] = total >> 16 & 0xFF;
uartBuf[2] = total >> 8 & 0xFF;
uartBuf[3] = total & 0xFF; 
uartBuf[4] = '\n';
UART_1_PutString(uartBuf); //doesn't work
}

//uart.c
void UART_1_PutString(const char8 string[]) 
{
...
}
```

However in the function UART_1_PutString, string always points to '\0' rather than uartBuf?
What could be the problem? Theoretically the variable uartBuf shouldn't be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: Where's the `typedef` for `char8`? Or perhaps that's a typo...

Comment: typedef          char   char8;

Comment: Arrays don't point. Pointers do point. Although this is a decayed array, which is actually a pointer, you should treat it as an array. Its contents need to be accessed this way: `string[i]`. Do you mean that `string[0] == '\0'` always?  Maybe `(total >> 24 & 0xFF) == 0` always.

Comment: change it to `void UART_1_PutString(const char * string)`

Comment: @bigwillydos That's the same thing.

Comment: I would advise not to use any ugly `typedef`s such as `char8` if they mean `char`.  Also, maybe `unsigned char` would be more suited for this task (unless you are forced to use `char` because of some library).

Comment: @CacahueteFrito - Your comment helped me solve the problem! uartBuf[0] was 0 under many conditions. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems correct

Do you mean that `string[0] == '\0'`?

Maybe `(total >> 24 & 0xFF) == 0` always (or most of the times).

**EDIT:**

The function should be

```
void UART_1_PutString(const volatile unsigned char buff[]);
```

It shouldn't be called string, because it's not text, it's just a buffer (it looks like it at least).

`unsigned` because the "string", comes from some unsigned bit manipulation after some maths, which could cause an invalid signed value (unlikely to fail, but the rule should be: `char` for text, `unsigned char` for unknown data (everything else)).

`volatile` because if not, you are discarding the `volatile` qualifier.  A compiler with high enough flags (in GCC: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` will highlight almost everything as errors) will warn you about that.  The compiler could think that the contents of the function can be simplified even before knowing that you will call it with `volatile` data, and therefore will optimize something which shouldn't be optimized.

You could also add the `restrict` keyword (C11) if no other function will access that buffer at the same time, so that you help the compiler produce better code:

```
void UART_1_PutString(const volatile unsigned char buff[restrict]);
```

**EDIT2:**

You should state the size of the buffer if it is only going to be called with that buffer, or also pass the size of the buffer to the function if not:

```
void UART_1_PutString(const volatile unsigned char buff[restrict 6]);
```

(6 should probably be replaced by some macro) or

```
void UART_1_PutString(size_t size, const volatile unsigned char buff[restrict size]);
```